# Publisher() doesn't work in Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am rewriting my program in MVC pattern, everything was okay, but now it's not. Publisher doesn't send message to the subscriber.

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
from threading import Thread

Publisher = pub.Publisher()

class GameDataLoading(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = DataLoadingView()
        self.view.Center()
        self.view.Show()

        Publisher().subscribe(self.test, 'test')
        LoadGameData().start()

    def test(self, data):
        print 'working'

class LoadGameData(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadGameData, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        wx.CallAfter(Publisher().sendMessage, 'test')
```

What can be wrong in this code?

Comment: In the code, two separated `Publisher` instances are created. Make a single instance, and use it both in `GameDataLoading`, `LoadGameData`. (assuming `Publisher` is not a singleton class)

Comment: No, this is one instance of Publisher. There is a global variable Publisher = pub.Publisher(). And yes, Publisher is a singleton class.

Comment: Please update the question with the content of the `Publisher`.

Answer (score 0):

Does the code keep a reference for `GameDataLoading` object?

For example, the following code does not work. But if you replace `GameDataLoading()` with `loading = GameDataLoading()`, it works.

```
from threading import Thread
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
import wx

Publisher = pub.Publisher()

class GameDataLoading(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = wx.Frame(None)
        self.view.Center()
        self.view.Show()

        Publisher().subscribe(self.test, 'test')
        LoadGameData().start()

    def test(self, data):
        print 'working'

class LoadGameData(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadGameData, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        wx.CallAfter(Publisher().sendMessage, 'test')

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
GameDataLoading()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You don't even understand... I use CallAfter, not CallLater. CallAfter method doesn't have millis argument. (see the documentation: http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#CallAfter)